# Slide through view controllers but not with the UISwipeGestureRecognizer

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, storyboard, uiswipegesturerecognizer

Here is my issue, i got 5 view controllers and i can switch between them trough swipe with the UISwipeGestureRecognizer class and xcode's storyboard.

So this works, but, i dont like the slide effect. I like to make it in a way so you can exactly slide the view to another by dragging it.

Can anyone send me in the right direction? I searched on the internet but i cant find any functions or tutorial on how to do this.

Thanks in advance!

**Edit:
Im not looking the scroll view. Because this will result in some white spaces when i have 3 slides vertical for slide 1 and 5 slides vertical for slide 2.
Hope u guys can follow me!**

**Edit:
This is what i try to accomplish.**
[image]
**

Comment: Do they need to be separate view controllers? i.e. can you just use a scroll view with paging enabled?

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, i can use the scroll view but its hard to design the other pages with the scroll view. I thought maby there is a way to scroll view controllers because that would be great to design on.

Comment: I update answer with sample project, it might helps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can use `UIScrollView` for your purposes. Check [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/PageControl/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007795) Apple's sample code.

**UPDATE:**
[Here is](https://github.com/leon4uk/ScrollViews) sample project that you need. I think it will be helpful. Sorry for naming - first use of github.
How it works:
- Creating root `UIScrollView` with set of "Root slides"
- Each "Root slide" has `UIScrollView` with `View`s that scrolls vertically
- Added check - we can scroll horizontally only from "Root slide"

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but that is not what i am looking for like i mentioned above. Thanks again.

Comment: What if you will try use one `UIScrollView` for scrolling "Root slides" and each "root slide" will have own `UIScrollView` to scroll subviews?

Comment: Thanks Leon, great sample project! Exactly what i was looking for, not the best because it generates the view controllers programmatically but i will figure it out! Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Use a `UIPanGestureRecognizer` instead and start the transition, if it was panned long enough.

Also you could try to use one paged ScrollView for each vertical slide and put them all together in a paged horicontal scrollview.

Comment: Were you suggesting to not use the UIPageControl?  Im building a camera that should pan to view assets like Apple's Camera.app.  Not sure if UIScrollView will be best or Using UIPageControl and overriding the gesture to have a timeout as you suggested.